# Indentation issue python

Tags: python, comments, indentation

I am a newbie to python and I have an indentation error message when I commented ('#') the two last lines of the following code :

```
    try:
        return get_callable(callback), {}
#   except (ImportError, AttributeError), e:
#       raise ViewDoesNotExist("Tried %s. Error was: %s" % (callback, st    r(e)))
```

Can anybody help ?

Comment: @Acorn : Sorry I was also editing my code. But why have I been down voted ?

Comment: A try block must be closed with a except

Comment: Here's the message : def resolve404(self):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When commenting out a `try` / `except`, place a `if True: #` in front of the `try`:

```
    if True: #try:
        return get_callable(callback), {}
#   except (ImportError, AttributeError), e:
#       raise ViewDoesNotExist("Tried %s. Error was: %s" % (callback, st    r(e)))
```

This makes for correct syntax without having to de-dent the inner block. You could also add a `finally: pass` block *after* the commented `except`:

```
    try:
        return get_callable(callback), {}
#   except (ImportError, AttributeError), e:
#       raise ViewDoesNotExist("Tried %s. Error was: %s" % (callback, st    r(e)))
    finally:
        pass
```

Your only other option is to comment out the `try:` line as well, *and* remove the indentation of the block:

```
#   try:
    return get_callable(callback), {}
#   except (ImportError, AttributeError), e:
#       raise ViewDoesNotExist("Tried %s. Error was: %s" % (callback, st    r(e)))
```

You cannot leave a bare `try:` in place without an `except` or `finally` block to complete it.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is no longer syntactically valid. The except clause is a required companion of the try clause.

Comment: Oh ok, I know nothing from python, how can I put a 'null code' to the except clause, so it doesn't affect the running of the code ?

Comment: @user1611830 I don't know what you mean. Do you want the exception to still be caught, but do nothing on that event, or do you want the exception to propagate as if the clause weren't there?

Answer (score 2):

If there is not another `except` statement, python is looking for an except statement and instead likely sees an unindented line.

So you might think, "why is this an *indentation* error? I'm just missing an `except`, which doesn't have anything to do with indents." The reason is that python "sees" an unindented line following a `try:` and expects it to be indented to be inside the `try`.